# Amend posts using wp_insert_post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I'm currently working with an XML feed to add posts to a custom post type using wp_insert_post().

It's all working fine but I was wondering if there's a way I can check if the post exists and amend any meta values in the post. The posts do have a unique ID associated to them if that helps. This is not a WordPress ID but a unique seven digit one.

So basically, is there a way to check against existing posts, update the information in them and add new posts if they don't yet exist?

Answer (score 0):

For starters you would need to associate your ID with the post. If you are not doing it already simply storing it in custom field will do.

Aside — long time ago I had a reasonable idea that GUID field is well suited for storing unique ID for the post. WordPress, however, is not reasonable. Don’t do *that*.

Then whenever you want to check for existing post you can query for posts (one post de facto in your case) which have that custom field key with that custom field value. See [custom field parameters for query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

If you get nothing back then there isn’t a post yet. Otherwise you get an existing post and use its ID to make updates to it.

Answer (score 0):

[From the Codex page for `wp_insert_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post):

> IMPORTANT: Setting a value for $post['ID'] WILL NOT create a post with
>   that ID number. Setting this value will cause the function to update
>   the post with that ID number with the other values specified in $post.
>   In short, to insert a new post, $post['ID'] must be blank or not set
>   at all.

You just need to supply your feed post with a matching WordPress id and the function will update instead of insert. Unfortunately, I don't know how the rest of your system works so providing more detail, much less code, isn't really possible.